# Are the eigenvectors of a power matrix A^k the eigenvectors of the matrix A?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $x\in\mathbb C^n$ is an eigenvector of $B\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ and $B=A^k$ for a certain $k\in\Bbb N$, is $x$ an eigenvector of $A\in\Bbb C^{n\times n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $A$ has only one eigenvector (or rather, a one dimensional eigenspace), $e_1$, but $B=A^2 = 0$ has all vectors as eigenvectors.

Comment: Simple as that... thanks! :)